# Как убрать подергивания блока при скроле?

Tags: javascript, css, foundation

Есть блок для мобильных устройств, который открывается / закрывается с помощью плагина `Toggler(Foundation)`.
Хочу сделать, чтобы блок скрывался не только по клику на кнопку, как сейчас, но и при скролле (или при клике вне блока). Сейчас, когда начинаешь скролить,- блок дергается и не всегда скрывается.
Как исправить баг, может выбрать другое событие?
Ниже пример для визуального отображения подергивания, код в проекте другой.
(Воспроизвести его через сниппет не получилось)
Закрываю блок с помощью метода плагина.

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       let menuStatus = $('#js-mobile-menu').attr('aria-expanded');
       if( menuStatus === 'true') {
          $('#js-mobile-menu').foundation('toggle');
       }
});
```

```js
$('#js-toggle-panel').click(function() {
  $('.callout').toggleClass('active');
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.callout').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.block {
  height: 800px;
  padding: 5rem
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

.callout {
  //display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -500px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 1rem;
  transition: all .45s;
}

.callout.active {
  //display: block;
  top: calc(100% + 1px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="block">
  <div class="row">
    <p><a id="js-toggle-panel">Toggle Panel</a></p>

    <div class="callout">
      <h4>Hello!</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta quas optio alias voluptas nobis iusto mollitia asperiores incidunt reprehenderit doloribus voluptatibus officiis minus, inventore, quasi nisi. Consequuntur, quidem. Sint, dicta?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда колесо крутится, возникает множество событий scroll.
Нужно прикрутить throttle/debounce, чтобы закрывание срабатывало один раз.

Answer (score 1):

Уважаемый, `toggleClass` меняет один на другой или добавляет и убирает, получается, что во время `scroll` без условия  ты постоянно меняешь `class`, из того, что я понял, тебе просто надо во время `scroll` `addClass` добавлять КЛАСС, а кликом удалять класс `removeClass`

```js
$('.callout').click(function() {
  return false;
  event.preventDefault();

});
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.callout').addClass('active');
});

$(window).click(function() {
  $('.callout').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.block {
  height: 800px;
  padding: 5rem
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

.callout {
  //display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -500px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 1rem;
  transition: all .45s;
}

.callout.active {
  //display: block;
  top: calc(100% + 1px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="block">
  <div class="row">
    <p><a id="js-toggle-panel">Toggle Panel</a></p>

    <div class="callout">
      <h4>Hello!</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta quas optio alias voluptas nobis iusto mollitia asperiores incidunt reprehenderit doloribus voluptatibus officiis minus, inventore, quasi nisi. Consequuntur, quidem. Sint, dicta?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Думаю, что скрипт немного дополнить нужно. Функция по клику остается с `.toggleClass` и по скролу нужно добавить событие с удалением класса при клике за пределами блока.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev, если функцию по клику оставить `.toggleClass` так он же по клику  будет выскакивать туда суда, он вроде хотел что бы блок появлялся по скролу? или я что то не так понял?

Comment: тут в вопросе вроде было сказано "Хочу сделать, чтобы блок скрывался не только по клику на кнопку, как сейчас, но и при скролле (или при клике вне блока)." Или же суть вопроса в том, что ему нужен банально `.toggleClass` при клике и `.removeClass` при скролле.